# Sub Query counting character strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, review, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
    FROM reviews
    GROUP BY user_id
) b ON b.user_id= b.user_id
```

I am trying to fit `WHERE LENGTH(review) > 100` in this somewhere but every I put it, it gives me problems.

The sub-query above counts all total reviews by `user_id`.  I simply want to add one more qualification.  Only count reviews greater than 100 length.

On a side note, I've seen the function `CHAR_LENGTH` -- not sure if that i what I need either.

**EDIT:**

Here is complete query working perfectly as expected for my needs:

```
    static public $top_users = "
            SELECT  u.username, u.score,
            (COALESCE(a.totalCount, 0) * 4) +
            (COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) * 5) +
            (COALESCE(c.totalCount, 0) * 1)  +
            (COALESCE(d.totalCount, 0) * 2)  +
            (COALESCE(u.friend_points, 0)) AS totalScore
            FROM users u 
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
                    FROM items 
                    GROUP BY user_id
                ) a ON a.user_id= u.user_id
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
                    FROM reviews
                    GROUP BY user_id
                ) b ON b.user_id= u.user_id
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
                    FROM ratings
                    GROUP BY user_id
                ) c ON c.user_id = u.user_id
             LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
                    FROM comments
                    GROUP BY user_id
                ) d ON d.user_id = u.user_id

                ORDER BY totalScore DESC LIMIT 25;";
```

Comment: You can't select field values in a group by query that aren't included in the group by.  I don't see how this is working...

Comment: I can only tell you that it is, I will post full working code.

Comment: @wcm Because MySQL ridiculously allows this type of functionality. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Aarolama for the correction and your link in your answer.  I think I understand why they allow it but it just feels so wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in bytes. You probably want `CHAR_LENGTH()` as it will give you the actual characters.

```
SELECT user_id, review, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
FROM reviews
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(review) > 100
GROUP BY user_id, review
```

You're also not using `GROUP BY` correctly.

[See the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: This did it.  I just had to remove the Group By `review` and only `user_id`

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk . . . You should elaborate on why you are saying that.  The original query uses `group by` and the Hidden Columns (mis)feature of MySQL to return an arbitrary review.  I don't like this feature.  BUT . . . the goal seems to be to get the count of reviews and that is what the subquery is doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I may as well create a Gist to explain it. Pointing to the documentation seems sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The query that you want is:

```
LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount,
                           sum(case when length(review) > 100 then 1 else 0 end
                              ) as NumLongReviews
                    FROM reviews
                    GROUP BY user_id
                ) b ON b.user_id= b.user_id
```

This counts both the reviews and the "long" reviews.  That count is done using a `case` statement nested in a `sum()` function.